# two #id's in an if statement for checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm pretty new to Jquery and I have this jquery to check if checkboxes are checked. If not the form should not execute.

It worked fine with only the `#validCheck` id, but when I added the `#feeCheck` it doesn't matter witch one is checked, the form executes.

what I want is that the both checkboxes must be checked for the form to execute. If they are both not checked the form should not execute.

```
  if(!($('#validCheckbox , #feeCheckbox').prop('checked')))
{
  errorMessage += "You must check the checkboxes to continue!<br/>";
  errorCounter++;
  ok = false;
  $("#errorDiv").css({"backgroundColor": "#f9f9f9", "color": "#D2002C", "padding": "10px"});
  $("#errorDiv").html(errorMessage);

}
```

Do I really have to write two seperate if statements for each checkbox?

I'm reusing the script for multiple forms, some of them have both checkboxes some only have the `#validCheck`

can someone help me with this.

Comment: If you're still struggling with the missing element, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need two separate queries.  From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)...

> Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements

So you need to make it...

```
if(!($('#validCheckbox').prop('checked') && $('#feeCheckbox').prop('checked')))
```

---

In response to the OP's comments to madalinivascu, the following would work for situations where `#feeCheckbox` doesn't exist...

```
var $feeCheckbox = $("#feeCheckbox");
if (!$("#validCheckbox").prop("checked") || ($feeCheckbox.length > 0 && !$feeCheckbox.prop("checked"))) {
  ...
}
```

The result being that if the `#validCheckbox` is set to false, you enter the `if`... **or** if `#feeCheckbox` is found **and** it is set to false you enter the `if`.

By putting the jquery object into the variable, you don't have to find it multiple times.

Comment: Your updated approach did exactly what I was looking for.... it saved my day thank you

Comment: You're very welcome @Slowboy - I'm glad I could help. Good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 2):

Jquery doesn't do logical operations on the property of the objects so you need to split the selector

```
if(!($('#validCheckbox').prop('checked') && $('#feeCheckbox').prop('checked')))
```

Comment: that make sense,  this is working...Tahnk you.... But in some forms the #feeCheckbox is not present,  then the form will not execute.... is there away to change that?

Comment: or do `if((!($('#validCheckbox').prop('checked') && $('#feeCheckbox').prop('checked'))) ||  (!$('#validCheckbox').prop('checked') && $('#feeCheckbox').length ==0))`

Comment: it's not executing without the #feeCheckbox if I use this approach

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!$('#validCheckbox').is(':checked') && !$('#feeCheckbox').is(':checked'))
```

Comment: A bit of explanations would make this answer better.